# How to create a full screen window using ncurses in linux?

Tags: c++, terminal, ncurses

When initializing a window in ncurses, it creates an 80x24 window, but I want the window to take up my entire screen. How do I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by window? Is it ncurses window or terminal window?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the screen dimensions with

```
int x,y;
initscr();
getmaxyx(stdscr,y,x);
```

and then use

`wresize`

to build a full screen window.

Comment: not really.  OP's question lacks an example, but the more likely interpretation is that the screensize is unknown.

Comment: What not really? It works. One can also directly use newwin(0, 0, 0, 0); to create a full-screen window.

Comment: If the idea is to maximize the terminal in which the program runs, one could for instance call the external `xdotool key "Super_L+Page_up"` to maximize/restore the terminal window.

Comment: `"Super_L+Page_Up"` works on KDE, whereas `"Ctrl+Super_L+Up"` works on Gnome - see also `dconf-editor`.